# looking through a string for a substring

Tags: python, string, count, substring

This code seems to work if I use an alternative string and substring but as soon as a letter appears twice in a row this function flipsout, can someone correct me?
I want it to return True or False, depending on, if the substring occurs 'n' or more times!

```
def nCount(s,substr,n):
    count = 0
    for i in s:
        if len(s[s.index(i):]) >= len(substr):
            print s[s.index(i):(s.index(i)+(len(substr)))]
            if (s[s.index(i):(s.index(i)+(len(substr)))] == substr):

                count += 1
    if (count >= n):
        return True
    return False

print nCount("Mississippi", "si", 3)
```

Comment: please correct your post, I cannot read it well.
and please be details what you want to gain with that code..

Comment: "flips out"? Can you be a bit more specific? Don't expect everyone to open an IDE and test your code.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a class assignment where you have to build everything from scratch, but if not… you realize that [`s.count(substr)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) can replace the entire loop that you're having so much trouble writing, right?

Comment: Here's a hint that might help: `s.index(i)` returns the _first_ index where the substring is found. This means that each time you're searching for, say, `'i'`, you're finding the first occurrence of it.

Comment: @ChristianTernus: Nice tip, but… I'm not sure what he's trying to use `index` for in the first place. He's just getting the first index of each latter in the `s` string, which doesn't help in any way.

Comment: You should change your for loop to `for i in range(len(s))`

Comment: @kren470: That's usually a bad idea. When you want the index and the value, that's exactly what `enumerate` is for…

Comment: @abarnert Why would he want the value? He only needs index (for slicing), enumerate would also give him the current char, which would be useless in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any way this algorithm would make sense. `for i in s` is going to loop over all of the letters in `"Mississippi"`. `s.index(i)` is going to return the first index of each such letter. So, that's going to be 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 8, 8, 1. I can't imagine anything useful you could do with that.

When you need the index and the value, rather than trying to calculate the index from the value (which is difficult or impossible) or the value from the index (which is easy, but tedious), just use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). That's what it's for:

```
for index, i in enumerate(s):
```

And then everywhere you were doing `s.index(i)`, just use `index`.

---

Of course this is trivial to solve with the [`count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method on strings.

```
def nCount(s, subst, n):
    return s.count(substr) >= n
```

Answer (score 0):

A whole lot easier with a regex:

```
import re

def nCount(s, subst, n):
    return len(re.findall(subst, s))>=n

print nCount("Mississippi", "si", 3)    # False
print nCount("Mississippi", "si", 2)    # True
```

Comment: Why use a regex? `s.count(subst)` is a whole lot simpler and more readable than `len(re.findall(subst, s))`. Plus, it'll be faster, and work for patterns that happen to have regex special characters in them, as so on.